# Print the lowest score in guessing game

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class GuessingGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int target;
        int guess;
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int game = 0;
        int score = 1;
        String answer;
        do {
            target = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
            System.out.print("Guess a number between 1 and 100: ");
            guess = keyboard.nextInt();
            while (guess != target) {
                if (target < guess)
                    System.out.println("The number is lower, Try again");
                else
                    System.out.println("The number is higher, Try again");
                System.out.print("Guess a number between 1 and 100: ");
                guess = keyboard.nextInt();
                score++;
            }
            System.out.println("You guessed correctly!!");
            System.out.println("Your score is " + score);
            System.out.print("Play another game, yes(or no):");
            answer = keyboard.next();
            game++;
            score = 1;
        } while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
        // end of game information
        System.out.println("Game summary");
        System.out.print("\tNumber of games played:\t" + game);
        System.out.println("\tbest score" + score);
    }
}
```

I'm learning how to use the Random class by making a guessing game that generates a number between 1 and 100. Every time the user makes a guess the score goes up. I am unsure on how I can print the lowest score. The program adds the total amount of scores from both games instead of printing the lowest score.

Comment: Show some code.

Comment: You need to store one score per game or, which might be easier, keep the lowest score in a separate variable and do a comparison after each game between latest and lowest score

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you can print it, you need to compute it.

Two things are needed:
1. The score for each game
2. The lowest score so far

In order for your 'score' variable to compute the score for the current game, it needs to be reset to 1 for each game.  Thus, `score = 1` immediately after the `do {` where a new game starts.

And in order to track the lowest, you need to declare `int lowestScore = 999999999` (explained later) and, after each game (just outside the loop on `guess != target`) you write `if (score < lowestScore) lowestScore = score`.

Why that 999999999?  Well, it's a cheap way to ensure that the first score, which will be the lowest score so far by definition, is going to be remembered as the lowest score.  Unless you have someone who's willing to type in a billion wrong guesses.

Comment: It’s better to use a well known and established constant like Integer.MAX_VALUE than to make up your own definition of what a very large value is

Comment: I assumed someone would say that, but in simple cases like this, I prefer a sentinel that's visually obvious and which has no practical disadvantage. Bear in mind we're at 'beginner level' here. Still, the OP can be the judge.